# Freeing array of dynamic strings / lines in C

Tags: c, string, sorting, malloc, free

I am writing a program that is sorting the lines from the input text file. It does its job, however I get memory leaks using valgrind.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* getline(FILE * infile)
{
    int size = 1024;
    char * line = (char*)malloc(size);
    int temp;

    int i=0;
    do
    {
        (temp = fgetc(infile));
        if (temp !=EOF)
            line[i++]=(char)temp;
        if (i>=size)    
        {
            size*=2;
            line = (char*)realloc(line, size);
        }

    }while (temp != '\n' && temp !=EOF);
    if (temp==EOF)
        return NULL;
    return line;
}

void print_line (char * line)
{
    printf("%s", line);
}

int myCompare (const void * a, const void * b )
{
    const char *pa = *(const char**)a;
    const char *pb = *(const char**)b;

    return strcmp(pa,pb);
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE * infile;
    FILE * outfile;

    infile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (infile==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
        exit(3);
    }
    outfile = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if (outfile==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
        exit(3);
    }
    char * line;
    char **all_lines;
    int nlines=0;

    while((line=getline(infile))!=NULL)
    {
        print_line(line);
        nlines++;
    }

    all_lines=malloc(nlines*sizeof(char*));
    rewind(infile);
    int j=0;
    printf("%d\n\n", nlines);

    while((line=getline(infile))!=NULL)
    {

        all_lines[j]=line;
        j++;
    }

    qsort(all_lines, nlines, sizeof(char*), myCompare);

    for (int i=0; i<nlines;i++)
    {
        print_line(all_lines[i]);
        fprintf(outfile, "%s", all_lines[i]);
    }

    for(int i =0; i<nlines;i++)
    {
        free(all_lines[i]);
    }

    free(all_lines);
    fclose(infile);
    fclose(outfile);
    return 0;   
}
```

Any ideas where they might come from? I loop over all_lines[] and free the content, then free all_lines itself.

UPDATE:

Ok, so I've done the updates you have suggested. However, now valgrind throws error for functions fprintf in my program. Here is what it says:

```
11 errors in context 2 of 2:

==3646== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3646==    at 0x40BA4B1: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1601)
==3646==    by 0x40C0F7F: printf (printf.c:35)
==3646==    by 0x80487B8: print_line (sort_lines.c:44)
==3646==    by 0x804887D: main (sort_lines.c:77)
==3646==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==3646==    at 0x4024D12: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:476)
==3646==    by 0x8048766: getline (sort_lines.c:30)
==3646==    by 0x804889A: main (sort_lines.c:75)
```

I would like to know why it reports error on simply fprintf those lines to a text file. I've looked up that it is something concerning gcc optimalization turning fprint into fputs but I dont get this idea

Comment: `if (temp==EOF)   return NULL;` <- memory leak

Comment: It doesn't look like you're freeing your "line" variable on line 8.

Comment: `while((line=getline(infile))!=NULL)` <- memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

function `getline`:

- the string in the `line` buffer is not properly `'\0'` terminated at the end of the `do / while` loop.
- It does not `free` the `line` buffer upon end of file, hence **memory leak**.
- It does not return a partial line at end of file if the file does not end with a `'\n'`.
- neither `malloc` not `realloc` return values are checked for memory allocation failure.
- You should `realloc` the `line` to the actual size used to reduce the amount of memory consumed.  Currently, you allocate at least 1024 bytes per line.  Sorting the dictionary will require **100 times** more memory than needed!

function `MyCompare`:

The lines read include the `'\n'` at the end.  Comparison may yield unexpected results: `"Hello\tworld\n"` will come before `"Hello\n"`.  You should strip the `'\n'` in `getline` and modify the `printf` formats appropriately.

function `main`:

- You do not check if command line arguments are actually provided before trying to open them with `fopen`, invoking undefined behaviour
- The first loop that counts the number of lines does not `free` the lines returned by `getline`... **big memory leak**!
- The input stream cannot always be `rewind`ed.  If your program is given its input via a pipe, `rewind` will fail except for very small input sizes.
- The number of lines read in the second loop may be different from the one counted in the first loop if the file was modified asynchronously by another process.  It the file grew, you invoke undefined behaviour when you load it, if it shrank, you invoke undefined behaviour when you sort the array.  You should reallocate the `all_lines` array as you read the lines in a single loop.

Printing the lines before sort is not very useful and complicates testing.

Comment: Ok, so I've done the updates you have suggested. However, now valgrind throws error for functions fprintf in my program. Here is what it says:

Comment: @Grzegorz: did you tack the `'\0'` at the end of the buffer?  The buffer should be llocted/reallocated with an extra byte for this.  Can you post the updated code on a paste bin, or ask a new question. Do not fix the code in the original question.